# Subtract all rows from first row

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following file

```
cat input.dat
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 0 5
 4 3 1 2 5
```

I want to subtract all the rows from the first one starting from the second row in bash.
The desired output

```
 1  2 3 4 5
 0  0 0 4 0
-3 -1 2 2 0
```

Basically

```
row1-row2
row1-row3
...
```

**How to efficiently subtract all rows/lines from the first row/line in a file?**

`Do` loop is one option to go but probably not the efficient one in complicated cases.

EDIT:

The question(and the answer as well) might be an overlap with

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261079/how-to-subtract-rows-from-first-row-using-awk

```
 awk '{ if (NR == 1) 
      { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++){ first_row[i] = $i} } 
 else { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++){ printf "%s ", first_row[i] - $i }; 
      printf "\n"}}' input.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` and an array (`head`) which contains first row:

```
awk '{
       if(NR==1){
         split($0,head);
         for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ printf("%3d", $i) }
       }
       else{
         for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ printf("%3d", head[i]-$i) }
       }
       print ""
     }' input.dat
```

Output:

```
  1  2  3  4  5
  0  0  0  4  0
 -3 -1  2  2  0
```

Answer (score 1):

In AWK,

File `tabsub.awk`:

```
NR == 1 {
    print
    i = 1
    while (i <= NF) {
        H_REF[i] = $i
        i++
    }
    next
}
NR > 1 {
    s = ""
    i = 1
    while (i <= NF) {
        s = s " " (H_REF[i] - $i)
        i++
    }
    print s
    next
}
```

Called like:

```sh
$ awk -f tabsub.awk input.dat
```

Comment: It is useful to wait with the answer until the questioner has shown what he has done to answer the question himself.

Comment: `NR==1{split($0,f)}`, using all uppercase variable names is a bad habit.  `while` loop is better off as `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=f[i]-$i}1; NR==1{split($0,f)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure `bash` solution:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

INPUT_FILENAME="$1"

declare -i N_LINE=0
declare -i N_FIELD=0
declare NEW_LINE=
while read LINE; do
    (( N_LINE++ ))
    N_FIELD=0
    NEW_LINE=
    if [[ -z "${LINE}" ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    while [[ "${LINE}" =~ \  ]]; do
        (( N_FIELD++ ))
        if [[ ${N_LINE} -eq 1 ]]; then
            H_REF[N_FIELD]="${LINE%% *}"
            NEW_LINE="${NEW_LINE} ${H_REF[N_FIELD]}"
        else
            NEW_LINE="${NEW_LINE} $(( ${H_REF[N_FIELD]} - ${LINE%% *} ))"
        fi
        LINE="${LINE#* }"
    done
    if [[ -n "${LINE}" ]]; then
        (( N_FIELD++ ))
        if [[ ${N_LINE} -eq 1 ]]; then
            H_REF[N_FIELD]="${LINE}"
            NEW_LINE="${NEW_LINE} ${H_REF[N_FIELD]}"
        else
            NEW_LINE="${NEW_LINE} $(( ${H_REF[N_FIELD]} - ${LINE%% *} ))"
        fi
    fi
    echo "${NEW_LINE}"
done < <(cat "${INPUT_FILENAME}"; echo)
```

Called like:

```sh
$ tabsub.sh input.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed -E '1h;1ba;G;s/^/\n/;:b;s/\n (\S+)(.*)\n (\S+)/ $((\3-\1))\n\2\n/;tb;s/\n//g
        :a;s/.*/printf "%3d" &/e'  file
```

Make a copy of the first line and then print it formatted.

Append the copy of the first line to each subsequent line and using pattern matching replace each integer on the second line by an arithmetic expression, subtracting it from the integer situated in same place on the first line.

Append the expressions to a `printf` command and evaluate.